# Bash chaining commands with vs without semi-colon

Tags: python, bash

Observed an interesting bash behavior that I don't understand.

Basically, when chaining commands in bash, whether there's a semi-colon between the two commands seem to make a difference in bash behavior. In particular the two examples below, one can read the env variable in Python, the other cannot

```
yuli@yuli-desktop:~$ A=1; python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['A']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'A'
>>> exit()
```

In a new bash process:

```
yuli@yuli-desktop:~$  A=1 python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
>>>
>>> os.environ['A']
'1'
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not chaining two commands in the second example.

When you run a command in bash, you can set per-command environment variables by prefixing the command line with variable assignments, as in:

```
A=1 B=2 COLOR=red python3
```

In this case, those variables (`A`, `B`, `COLOR`) will be available in the environment of the command:

```
>>> os.getenv('COLOR')
'red'
```

In the first example, the semicolon splits the command line into two independent commands. Since the `python3` command has no variable assignments associated with it, you're not setting any environment variables. Instead, you've set a shell-local variable `A` that would be visible in the shell but not in any child processes.

You can see documentation about this in the "SHELL GRAMMAR" section of the [bash man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

---

In comments, ErikMD mentions the `export` shell built-in, which is used to set persistent environment variables:

```
$ export COLOR=red
```

Or:

```
$ COLOR=red
$ export COLOR
```

An environment variable set this way will persist until explicitly unset and will be available in all subsequent commands. Contrast that with a variable set as part of a command invocation (as discussed earlier in this answer), which is only available for the duration of that command.

Comment: Also, you may want to mention the `export` shell builtin?

Comment: The explanation of the function of `export` is confusing.  It is not necessary to use `export` to make a shell variable persistent.  They last until unset in any case.  What `export` does is (only) make the shell put the variable in the environment of all subsequent commands, until it is unset or unexported.  The shell doesn't do that for non-exported variables.

Comment: Without `export` you don't get an environment variable, you get a shell local variable, which is sort of the point I was trying to make. I'm happy for suggestions on alternate phrasing.

Comment: Basically, `export` sets the export attribute on a *name* (whether there is a variable by that name or not). When a child process is created, any variable whose name has the export attribute set is used to create a variable with the same name and value in the environment of the child process.

Comment: (sorry for late reply) @larsks thanks! − actually I had mentioned the `export` builtin especially because the OP's question dealt with `A=1; python3` while `export A=1; python3` would have given the "expected" behavior from this viewpoint…